# toLocaleDateString() method not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am using toLocaleDateString() method to localize dates according to the selected language in my application. It is working fine in Chrome and IE but it's not working in Safari. I have gone through the documentation for the method and it says localization is not supported in Safari. Any suggestions for toLocaleDateString() method alternative with customizable date format...???

Answer (score -2):

> Create your own defination and call it .. it might work for you

```
function getLocaleDateString(){

var formats = {
   "ar-SA" : "dd/MM/yy",
   "bg-BG" : "dd.M.yyyy",
   "ca-ES" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "zh-TW" : "yyyy/M/d",
   "cs-CZ" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "da-DK" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "de-DE" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "el-GR" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "en-US" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "fi-FI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "fr-FR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "he-IL" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "hu-HU" : "yyyy. MM. dd.",
   "is-IS" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "it-IT" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ja-JP" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "ko-KR" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "nl-NL" : "d-M-yyyy",
   "nb-NO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "pl-PL" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "pt-BR" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "ro-RO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ru-RU" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "hr-HR" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "sk-SK" : "d. M. yyyy",
   "sq-AL" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "sv-SE" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "th-TH" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "tr-TR" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ur-PK" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "id-ID" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "uk-UA" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "be-BY" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "sl-SI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "et-EE" : "d.MM.yyyy",
   "lv-LV" : "yyyy.MM.dd.",
   "lt-LT" : "yyyy.MM.dd",
   "fa-IR" : "MM/dd/yyyy",
   "vi-VN" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "hy-AM" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "az-Latn-AZ" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "eu-ES" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "mk-MK" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "af-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "ka-GE" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "fo-FO" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "hi-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "ms-MY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "kk-KZ" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ky-KG" : "dd.MM.yy",
   "sw-KE" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "uz-Latn-UZ" : "dd/MM yyyy",
   "tt-RU" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "pa-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "gu-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "ta-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "te-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "kn-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "mr-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "sa-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "mn-MN" : "yy.MM.dd",
   "gl-ES" : "dd/MM/yy",
   "kok-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "syr-SY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "dv-MV" : "dd/MM/yy",
   "ar-IQ" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "zh-CN" : "yyyy/M/d",
   "de-CH" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "en-GB" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-MX" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "fr-BE" : "d/MM/yyyy",
   "it-CH" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "nl-BE" : "d/MM/yyyy",
   "nn-NO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "pt-PT" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "sr-Latn-CS" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "sv-FI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "az-Cyrl-AZ" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ms-BN" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "uz-Cyrl-UZ" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ar-EG" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "zh-HK" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "de-AT" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "en-AU" : "d/MM/yyyy",
   "es-ES" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "fr-CA" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "sr-Cyrl-CS" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "ar-LY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "zh-SG" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "de-LU" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "en-CA" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-GT" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "fr-CH" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "ar-DZ" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "zh-MO" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "de-LI" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "en-NZ" : "d/MM/yyyy",
   "es-CR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "fr-LU" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-MA" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "en-IE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-PA" : "MM/dd/yyyy",
   "fr-MC" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-TN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "en-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "es-DO" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-OM" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-JM" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-VE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-YE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-029" : "MM/dd/yyyy",
   "es-CO" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-SY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-BZ" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-PE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-JO" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-TT" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-AR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-LB" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-ZW" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "es-EC" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-KW" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-PH" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "es-CL" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "ar-AE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-UY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-BH" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-PY" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ar-QA" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-BO" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-SV" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-HN" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-NI" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "es-PR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "am-ET" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "tzm-Latn-DZ" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "iu-Latn-CA" : "d/MM/yyyy",
   "sma-NO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "mn-Mong-CN" : "yyyy/M/d",
   "gd-GB" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "en-MY" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "prs-AF" : "dd/MM/yy",
   "bn-BD" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "wo-SN" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "rw-RW" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "qut-GT" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "sah-RU" : "MM.dd.yyyy",
   "gsw-FR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "co-FR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "oc-FR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "mi-NZ" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ga-IE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "se-SE" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "br-FR" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "smn-FI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "moh-CA" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "arn-CL" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "ii-CN" : "yyyy/M/d",
   "dsb-DE" : "d. M. yyyy",
   "ig-NG" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "kl-GL" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "lb-LU" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "ba-RU" : "dd.MM.yy",
   "nso-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "quz-BO" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "yo-NG" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "ha-Latn-NG" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "fil-PH" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "ps-AF" : "dd/MM/yy",
   "fy-NL" : "d-M-yyyy",
   "ne-NP" : "M/d/yyyy",
   "se-NO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "iu-Cans-CA" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "sr-Latn-RS" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "si-LK" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "sr-Cyrl-RS" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "lo-LA" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "km-KH" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "cy-GB" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "bo-CN" : "yyyy/M/d",
   "sms-FI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "as-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "ml-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "en-IN" : "dd-MM-yyyy",
   "or-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "bn-IN" : "dd-MM-yy",
   "tk-TM" : "dd.MM.yy",
   "bs-Latn-BA" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "mt-MT" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "sr-Cyrl-ME" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "se-FI" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "zu-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "xh-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "tn-ZA" : "yyyy/MM/dd",
   "hsb-DE" : "d. M. yyyy",
   "bs-Cyrl-BA" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "tg-Cyrl-TJ" : "dd.MM.yy",
   "sr-Latn-BA" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "smj-NO" : "dd.MM.yyyy",
   "rm-CH" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "smj-SE" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "quz-EC" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "quz-PE" : "dd/MM/yyyy",
   "hr-BA" : "d.M.yyyy.",
   "sr-Latn-ME" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "sma-SE" : "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "en-SG" : "d/M/yyyy",
   "ug-CN" : "yyyy-M-d",
   "sr-Cyrl-BA" : "d.M.yyyy",
   "es-US" : "M/d/yyyy"
};

   return formats[navigator.language] || 'dd/MM/yyyy';

}
```

Comment: I came across a plugin for proper date formatting and localization according to the selected language. Moment.js served the purpose...Thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: Sorry, but is a bad solution, you can't possibly expect someone to create 20 functions such as this one if they need to use 20 different formats in their app and to keep track of different formats around the world. That's what API's and libraries are for.